# Hardcoding Int reference as String to create JAR

Tags: android

I have a situation where I am creating JAR and I don't want to reference any of String or Int from /res/values. So I am hardcoding it everywhere

```
event_info.put("CLIENT_HALT", new EventInfo(R.string.client_halt, R.drawable.error, 0, EV_PRIO_HIGH, 0));
```

As you see "R.string.client_halt" refers to String "Halt" in res/values/abc.xml

But it is of type Int, hence I cannot do like this

```
event_info.put("CLIENT_HALT", new EventInfo("Halt", R.drawable.error, 0, EV_PRIO_HIGH, 0));
```

Below is EventInfo method

```
public EventInfo(int res_id_arg, int progress_arg, int priority_arg, int flags_arg)
    {
        res_id = res_id_arg;
        //icon_res_id = icon_res_id_arg;
        progress = progress_arg;
        priority = priority_arg;
        flags = flags_arg;
    }
```

How do I overcome this issue and hardcode int value in my method. I tried below case but it won't work and give me "NumberFormatException"

```
String halt = "Halt";
int foo = Integer.parseInt(halt);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By passing the id into constructor of your class, you can retrieve the string in the following way.

```
String stringValue = getResources().getString(R.string.client_halt);
```

If you are not able to get getResources() directly, pass the context in constructor and do the following

```
_context.getResources().getString(R.string.client_halt);
```

Comment: Stallion - It is again the same thing. When the class will run it will search the resource and it will crash when it won't find any resource coz while creating JAR we do not include resources